# MPAndroidChart grouped barchart onclick

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I've successfully used grouped barchart. I've got two bars per result (one red and one blue bar) but I haven't been able to retrieve X value when I click the blue one, only get the X value when I click the red bar.
[LINK TO IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h1QIx.jpg)
When I click either bar, the setOnChartValueSelectedListener method is called, but only when I click the red bar I get the XAxis value with this code:

```
barChart.setOnChartValueSelectedListener(new OnChartValueSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onValueSelected(Entry e, Highlight h) {
                if (null != barChart.getXAxis().getValueFormatter().getFormattedValue(e.getX(), barChart.getXAxis()) && !barChart.getXAxis().getValueFormatter().getFormattedValue(e.getX(), barChart.getXAxis()).isEmpty()) {
                      ContentManager.getInstance().setRegion(barChart.getXAxis().getValueFormatter().getFormattedValue(e.getX(), barChart.getXAxis()));
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected() {

            }
        });
```

how can I get the value when I click the blue bar?

```
barChart.getXAxis().getValueFormatter().getFormattedValue(e.getX(), barChart.getXAxis())
```

that line returns the value clicking the red bar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FIXED.
Just use Math.floor to use a rounded value on a bar click.